# Как оценить сложность алгоритма не зная кол-во итераций

Tags: c++, алгоритм, теория, сложность

Есть алгоритм

```
cin >> e;
int n = 1;
double S = 0, i = 0;

do
{
    S += i;
    i = 1 / (pow(3, n) - 1);
    n++;
} while (i >= e);

cout << "Сумма S = " << S;
```

он же на изображении

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По заданию необходимо определить оценку его сложности. Мне не понятно как это делать, т.к. у нас нет заранее известного количества элементов и т.д., и мы выполняем цикл пока очередной элемент не будет меньше точности.

По методичке алгоритм такой:

1. посчитать в лучшем случае - тут понятно, чтобы первый рассчитанный элемент был меньше точности.
2. посчитать в худшем случае - тут у меня проблемы. Была идея посчитать основываясь на том, что точность (Е) будет минимальной (по стандарту IEEE 754 для числа с плавающей точкой -1,17549435∙e-38), а первый рассчитанный элемент в сумме S будет максимальным, и двигаться к точности E очень медленно. Я думаю это корректно, но это сложно формализовать, возможно есть ответ проще.

Comment: `std::pow` вычисляется за константу. Хотя у вас целые аргументы, [стандарт](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow) говорит что они будут переведены в `double` у которого конечный алфавит. И в теории и на практике время вычисления `pow` не зависит от значений аргументов.

Answer (score 0):

Почему же это у нас нет заранее известного количества элементов?

Мы вполне можем вывести `n` из заданной точности `e` (здесь и далее `e` - это не число Эйлера, а точность из условия вопроса), составив элементарное уравнение `e=1/(3^n-1)` и решая его относительно `n`, решением которого будет `n=log(1+1/e)/log(3)`, где `log` - натуральный логарифм, хотя на оценку сложности это не влияет.

То есть очевидно у нас будет не менее `log(1+1/e)/log(3)` итераций, дальнейший расчёт временной сложности алгоритма зависит от того как мы считаем `3^n`. Обычно линейно в степень никто не возводит, а используют алгоритмы быстрого возведения в степень, где сложность `= log(n)`, хотя скорее всего в большинстве реализаций `std::pow` будет выполняться за `О(1)`, тут можно прочитать чуть подробнее: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13418180/time-complexity-of-c-math-library-pow-function

Таким образом получаем сложность нашего алгоритма вычисления суммы `= O(N*временная сложность pow)`, где `N = log(1+1/e)/log(3)`.

В случае если `std::pow` выполняется за константное время, получаем `O(log(1+1/e))`

Comment: Так как в указанной формуле нет N, то сложность получается константной.

Comment: @KoVadim, сложность зависит от `e`. Это необычно (в отличие от `N`) но так тоже можно. Время работы - функция от `e`. `O(-log(e))`.

Comment: @KoVadim почему это вдруг константной? что в качестве входных данных имеем, то в формуле сложности и получаем (в данном случае ```e```).

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy вы уверены, что ```О(-log(e))``` - это корректное преобразование из ```O(log(1+1/e))```? у меня как-то сходу не получается так

Comment: @timbars по отношению к n - константа.

Comment: `log(1 + 1/e) = log((e + 1) / e) = log(e + 1) - log(e)`. Первое слагамое ограничено (стремиться к нулю), второе неограниченно растёт. Оценки делаются для `e -> +0`, что необычно.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy да, действительно, забыл как-то в процессе, что считаем для ```e->0```, спасибо :)

Comment: @KoVadim всё равно не понимаю как это связано с тем, что сложность по вашему мнению константна, если в ней нет ```N```, которое я вообще ввёл только для замены громоздкой формулы с ```e```, а ```n``` в данной задаче так и вообще только индекс суммирования

Comment: Вы путаете n и N. Если написать формулу так, что бы в ней было e в явном виде, тогда все умозаключения имеют вид.